# ¿Como lleno una secuencia o arreglo de una clase en mi controlador?

Tags: c#, api

Estoy tratando de llenar los datos de una clase mediante un controlador pero al ejecutar me da error de instancia de objeto no establecida.

La clase es esta

```
  public partial class DTEDefTypeDocumentoEncabezadoEmisor {
  private string[] telefonoField;

  public string[] Telefono {
    get {
        return this.telefonoField;
    }
    set {
        this.telefonoField = value;
    }
 }
```

}

La forma en que trato de llenarlo es de esta forma

```
 DTEDefTypeDocumentoEncabezadoEmisor fact_emis = new DTEDefTypeDocumentoEncabezadoEmisor();
 fact_emis.Telefono[0] = "655549822";
 fact_emis.Telefono[1] = "151591955";
```

Cuando ejecuto el controlador me manda : 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Comment: No has inicializado tu arreglo de teléfonos

Comment: como lo puedo inicializar ??